# How to pass all array values to select statement at a time

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle11g, oracle10g, plsqldeveloper

Hi I am using a stored procedure which takes a string parameter

```
 '919860,919736,989087'
```

i am converting the string to array using apex_util.string_to_table

```
array  := apex_util.string_to_table('919860,919736,989087', ',');
```

Now i want to pass all the array values select statement.

```
insert into table2 select * from table1 where mobile in (**all array values**);
```

Answer (score 2):

You cannot use "array" variable in select statement, because local collection types not allowed in SQL statement.

One option that I personally prefer is use INSTR function to check whether value is in the list:

```
insert into table2 select * from table1
where INSTR( ',' || '919860,919736,989087' || ','
           , ',' || mobile || ',') > 0;
```

Other option you could write a pipelined function that would take the APEX_APPLICATION_GLOBAL.VC_ARR2 as an IN parameter, which could return a type of collection capable of being referenced by the TABLE function e.g:

```
  function array_rows(p_rows_in in APEX_APPLICATION_GLOBAL.VC_ARR2) return rows_t pipelined is
   begin

      for i in p_rows_in.first..p_rows_in.last loop

         pipe row(p_rows_in(i)); 

      end loop;

      return;

   end array_rows;


  insert into table2 select * from table1 where mobile in (select column_value 
  from table(pkg_pipe_func.piped_rows(apex_util.string_to_table('919860,919736,989087', ','))));
```

Answer (score 0):

The following should do. Untested (obviously).

```
insert into table2 
select * from table1
 where mobile in (select column_value from table(array));
```